# Returning method from class

Tags: python

I am new to python and learning classes. I have been having difficulties returning the method `charge` in the class below. I have tried using `.fee` and `charge` neither work.

```
class Job:

rate = 1.04


def __init__(self, location, salary, description, fee)  :
    self.location = location
    self.salary = salary
    self.description = description
    self.fee = fee



def Charge(self):
    self.fee = int( self.fee + Job.rate)


job1=Job("london",23000,"Accounts Assistant",1200)
job2=Job("london",25000,"Accounts Assistant",500)

job1.rate = 1.05

job1.charge()
print(job1.fee)
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you get an error message (then you should paste it here as well), or a result that you didn't expect (give us the erroneous output as well as what you expected). The indentation of your code is wrong. Everything that is part of the class should be indented.  Even correctly indented, you would get errors because of typos (`Charge` vs `charge`...) Please correct this first!

Comment: I think there is a typo. Charge method starts with a Caps 'C'.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit of formatting and some comments might assist.  I set the case of `charge` properly to `Charge` method name.  I created `Charge2` to show the difference between `Job.rate` and `self.rate` in the method

```
class Job:

    rate = 1.04

    def __init__(self, location, salary, description, fee)  :
        self.location = location
        self.salary = salary
        self.description = description
        self.fee = fee

    def Charge(self):
        self.fee = int( self.fee + Job.rate) # use class amount 1.04
    def Charge2(self):
        self.fee = int( self.fee + self.rate) # use instance (11.05 set below)

job1 = Job("london",23000,"Accounts Assistant",1200) # create instance
job2 = Job("london",25000,"Accounts Assistant",500) # create instance

job1.rate = 11.05

job1.Charge() # execute, adds 1.04 to 1200, then make int of that
print(job1.fee) # outputs 1201
job1.Charge2() # execute, adds 11.05 to 1201, then make int of that
print(job1.fee) # outputs 1212
print(job2.fee) # outputs 500 
job1.Charge2() # execute, adds 11.05 to 1212, then make int of that
print(job1.fee) # outputs 1223
job1.Charge() # execute, adds 1.04 to 1223, then make int of that
print(job1.fee) # outputs 1224
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution . I apologize for the sloppy presentation of my code I am trying to learn as fast as I can and I overlooked the indentation.I can see how the class variable can be changed for a specific instance and how the output can be different  if   I am  using either the class or instance.

Comment: You are welcome, if this does not cover your question let me know how it does not or what information is missing. IF desired, you can paste this code here http://pythonfiddle.com/ and see it run as a test.